# Group array items by dates

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, group-by

Say I have a list of objects like so

```
list <type>
---------------
o1: date-23.03
o2: date-23.03
o3: date-24.05
o4: date-25.05
```

How to make another list that contains inner lists of objects that has the same date? For example:

```
new list<list<type>>
-----------------------
List<type> innerList1 {o1, o2}
List<type> innerList2 {o3}
List<type> innerList3 {o4}
```

Possible LINQ solutions would be cool, but an algorithm would be nice too.

Comment: Don't use a `List<object>` but a `List<RealClass>`

Answer (score 8):

Don't use a `List<object>` but a `List<RealClass>`

Presuming that it's actually a known type and that it's a `DateTime` property:

```
List<List<ClassName>> objectsbyDate = listOfObjects
    .GroupBy(x => x.DateTimeProperty.Date)
    .Select(g => g.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

If it's actually `string` property as commented, why is that so? You should fix that. However, if you insist on a `string` you can still use `Enumerable.GroupBy`. But what if two objects have different years? You won't even mention it since the year is not stored.

Instead  convert a `DateTime` to string at the very last step if  you want to display it.

Comment: @V.G.: a string which represents a `DateTime`, why is that so? However, it only contains the month and day, so what if it contains different years? Do you always want to treat them as `DateTime.Today.Year`?

Answer (score 1):

Grouping by your date-object:

```
List<object> list = new List<object> {o1,o2,o3,o4};

var result = list.GroupBy(g => g);
foreach(var group in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
}
```

Comment: Use: list.GroupBy(g => g.ToList()).ToList(), to obtain List<List<object>>